# how to get fb friends list using Facebook iOS sdk 4.2

Tags: ios

I'm trying to find out all Facebook friends list by using the Facebook iOS sdk 4.2.

my code is

```
NSDictionary *param=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture.width(1000).height(1000), 
                     name, 
                     link", 
                     @"fields", 
                     nil];

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                              parameters:param
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler : ^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection       
          *connection, 
          id result, 
          NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"facebook friends :%@",result); // Handle the result
 }];
```

Comment: What is not working? Does "Error" say something?

Comment: This is response of code facebook friends :{
    data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 166;
    };
}

Comment: Why are you using iOS SDK 4.2?

Comment: @Droppy I think he means Facebook iOS SDK 4.2, not iOS 4.2